# Integrating WSO2 Siddhi CEP and Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, wso2, siddhi, stream-processing

I'm currently in the process of integrating WSO2's Siddhi CEP and Kafka. I want to produce a Siddhi stream by receiving events from Kafka. The Kafka data being received is in JSON format, where each event looks something like this:

```
{  
   "event":{  
      "orderID":"1532538588320",
      "timestamps":[  
         15325,
         153
      ],
      "earliestTime":1532538
   }
}
```

The SiddhiApp that I'm trying to run in the WSO2 stream processor looks like this:

```
@App:name('KafkaSiddhi')
@App:description('Consume events from a Kafka Topic and print the output.')

-- Streams
@source(type='kafka', 
topic.list = 'order-aggregates',
partition.no.list = '0',
threading.option = 'single.thread',
group.id = 'time-aggregates',
bootstrap.servers = 'localhost:9092, localhost:2181',
@map(type='json'))
define stream TimeAggregateStream (orderID string,timestamps 
object,earliestTime long);

@sink(type="log")
define stream TimeAggregateResultStream (orderID string, timestamps 
object, earliestTime long);

-- Queries
from TimeAggregateStream 
select orderID, timestamps, earliestTime
insert into TimeAggregateResultStream;
```

Running this app should log all of the data being updated in the order-aggregates Kafka cluster that I'm listening to. But I see no output whatsoever when click run.

I can tell that there is some type of interaction between the WSO2 stream processor and the order-aggregates topic, because error messages are outputted in real-time whenever I run the application with inconsistent data types for my stream schema. The error messages look like this:

```
[2018-07-25_10-14-37_224] ERROR 
{org.wso2.extension.siddhi.map.json.sourcemapper.JsonSourceMapper} - 
Json message {"event":{"orderID":"210000000016183","timestamps": 
[1532538627000],"earliestTime":1532538627000}} contains incompatible 
attribute types and values. Value 210000000016183 is not compatible with 
type LONG. Hence dropping the message. (Encoded)
```

However, when I have the schema setup correctly, I receive no output at all when I run the application. I really don't know how to make sense of this. When I try to debug this by putting a breakpoint into the line including 'insert into', the debugger never stops at that line.

Can anyone offer some insight on how to approach this issue?

Answer (score 1):

We have added the object support for json mapper extension in the latest release of the extension. Please download the extension[1] and replace the siddhi-map-json jar in /lib.

[1] https://store.wso2.com/store/assets/analyticsextension/details/0e6a6b38-f1d1-49f5-a685-e8c16741494d

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.